# Chromium compilation on embedded linux: artefacts shown on screen

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, chromium

I am trying to compile chromium (version 38) for a linux-based embedded device... and I am ok with compilation, but then chromium shows some artefacts on screen at runtime.

Some elements on the page are misplaced: playing around with the developer tools and enabling/disabling styles it *seems* (but I am not sure) that there is something wrong in CSS' "float" or "display" handling (see image below):

[image: chromium artefacts]
[image: chromium artefacts detail #1]

Furthermore the same (?) problem seems to affect some parts of Chromium UI too (e.g. in the developer toolbar the icons are misplaced, as you can see here below):

[image: chromium UI artefacts]

Maybe the problems are due to something missing (or misconfigured) at platform level (remember that it is running on top of a custom embedded linux)...

Is there anybody out there with a deep knowledge of chromium internals that can put me on the right way? If so, what in my platform could impact on both the browser UI and the page rendering?

Comment: It it only chromium with the issue? Have you tried a newer version?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see only chromium has such a problem... I cannot upgrade to last version: I am running on top of an embedded system and the last version of chromium which has been worked out to exploit the graphic hardware acceleration on the SoC that I am using is the version #38.

Comment: Looks like other folks with similar issues found resolution after disabling hardware acceleration in chromium. Not sure what hardware your embedded system is running (although I assume it's ARM and not Intel), but there's a number of intel chipset graphical issues that have been previous bugs (in chromium's bug tracker).

Comment: I know you wanted hardware acceleration, but try disabling that and see if the graphical glitches go away. might lead you down the right track to debug....

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I've already tried to disable the graphic acceleration (using `--disable-gpu` option on chromium command line, and double-checking through `chrome://gpu` that the hw accelaration is disabled) but the problem is still there... So I do not think that the problem is related to hw acceleration at all... Other ideas?